# Return variable in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to receive a AJAX request value, but alway receive undefined.

```
Panda.Meals.getMealById = function(id) {
  var meal = {};
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/admin.php?r=mess/getmealbyid",
    data: {"id": id},
    success: function(data) {
      meal = data;
    }
  });
  return meal;
}

var id = Panda.Meals.getMealById(10);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an asynchronous call. Your function will return just after calling `$.ajax()`. You have to provide a callback function to your `getMealById`.

See this example.

```
Panda.Meals.getMealById = function(id, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/admin.php?r=mess/getmealbyid",
    data: {"id": id},
    success: function(data) {
       callback(data);
    }
  });
}

Panda.Meals.getMealById(10, function(data) {
   var id = data;
   // do all your post processing here
});
```

Comment: +1 Good example, but I believe in this case you can just write `success: callback` instead of `success: function(data){callback(data);}`.

Comment: Yeah, that would do too, if don't need any decoration on response data

Comment: Yes, like in this case. If OP ever needs any, then he will need to use the `success` callback definition given by you.

Comment: Yeah, that would be his sole choice

Answer (score 3):

The function getMealById does not wait for the result of AJAX request. Since `$.ajax` does not block, the `getMealById` function returns before the AJAX request is finished.

Answer (score 2):

Your ajax call is asynchronous, so meal is undefined when you return the value.

You can do it like :

```
Panda.Meals.getMealById = function(id) {
    var meal = {};
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "http://localhost/admin.php?r=mess/getmealbyid",
        data: {"id": id},
        success: function(data) {
            meal = data;
        }
    });
    return meal;
}
```

Comment: Generally, because of how JavaScript works, the better idea is to use callbacks instead of relying on synchronous AJAX calls.